# Swift MapView display points of interest without the little icon (circle with image)

Tags: swift, mkmapview

In my swift app, I have a MKMapView where I am adding my own custom annotations that need to be circles with images. I want the map to display points of interest (restaurant names, tourist attractions, etc.) but I don't want the icons that sometimes appear with them. Is there any way to show the points of interest text without the associated icon?